# What is the general approach for constructing the subgroup lattice of a given group?

Tags: group-theory

I am interested in a general approach for obtaining the lattice of subgroups of a given group.

If this is not possible: is there a general approach for obtaining the lattice of subgroups for the symmetric groups $S_3,S_4,S_5,S_6$?

Comment: See https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_groups for a start